# Change buffer mode from outside the buffer. Taking the guise of another buffer

Tags: emacs, terminal

How can change the mode of a buffer from outside it i.e. while in another buffer, probably by using `eval`.

The problem is while in `term-char-mode` I can't operate <kbd>M-x</kbd>. In fact, getting out of that buffer is a not that easy a task. The option which works is changing to `line mode` from the *modeline*

[image]

to

[image]

and then using <kbd>M-x</kbd>, but that seems quite clumsy and crude. Any other way?

Basically performing action or passing a command from outside the buffer, say *X*, but pretending to be *X*.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly address your question, but note that it's quite easy to change between `term-line-mode` and `term-char-mode` when in `term-mode`:

By default, you're in `term-char-mode`. To go into `term-line-mode`, type

<kbd>C-c C-j</kbd>

In `term-line-mode` you can use your usual keybindings, including <kbd>M-x</kbd>.

To go back into `term-char-mode`, type

<kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>

Also note that keyboard shortcuts that usually begin with <kbd>C-x</kbd> are available as <kbd>C-c</kbd> in `term-char-mode`, e.g. `find-file` becomes <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>. This doesn't help with <kbd>M-x</kbd> though.

Comment: Pretty sure it does. Note that you have to be in `term-line-mode` -- are you saying that `C-C C-j` works, but you cannot go back to `term-char-mode`? Or what is the effect you're getting?

Comment: Yup. I can't go back to `term-char-mode` it says `undefined` combination.

Comment: Strange. Which version of Emacs are you running? I just tested with 24.3.1, invoked as `emacs -Q`, and it works as expected.

Comment: It's *GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7600) of 2013-03-18 on MARVIN*. And I have tried it with `emacs -q`after `eval`ing `(require 'term)`. `C-c C-k is undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You can "take the guise of another buffer" easily with macro `with-current-buffer`.  From the help:

```
(with-current-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME &rest BODY)

Execute the forms in BODY with BUFFER-OR-NAME temporarily current.
BUFFER-OR-NAME must be a buffer or the name of an existing buffer.
```

The fact that it accepts either the buffer name or a buffer reference is very convenient.  Personally, I find the "current" part of the macro's name a little counter-intuitive, as the BODY will be executed not in the current buffer but in another buffer as if it were the current.

Comment: FWIW, I think your last statement is confusing, if not incorrect. `with-current-buffer` *does*, in fact, change the buffer (using `set-buffer`) temporarily.  It simply restores the buffer that was current previously, afterward.  It does not execute anything "in another buffer as if it were the current" (though it's unclear what that last phrase might mean).  (Needless to say, your answer is otherwise correct --- +1.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") 'execute-extended-command)
```

to your `.emacs` to make <kbd>M-x</kbd> work in *char mode*.  For <kbd>C-x</kbd>, use

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (let (term-escape-char)
                              (term-set-escape-char ?\C-x)))
```

or use `ansi-term` instead of `term` to open a terminal.  This will allow you to use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to leave the buffer in *char mode*.

If you need to send <kbd>C-x</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd> to some application inside the *term*, you can do that using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.